# Use Range instead of PivotSelect --> Set rng = Selection

Tags: vba, excel, pivot

I know I can select a specific column in a `pivot table` in `VBA` using this:

```
pt.PivotSelect "Costs Alternative['1']", xlDataOnly, True
Set rng = Selection
```

Now, this is a bit annoying and not quite as fast and resilient as just going straight for:

```
Set rng = pt.PivotFields("Alternative").PivotFields("1").PivotItems("Costs").DataRange
```

My pivot table looks roughly like this:

```
+-------+-------------+--------+
|       | Alternative | Values |
|       | 1           |        |
| Price | ft          | Costs  |
+-------+-------------+--------+
| 6.58  | 6.00        | 39.48  |
| 2.00  | 2.00        | 4.00   |
| 0.30  | 6.00        | 1.80   |
| Total | 14.00       | 45.28  |
+-------+-------------+--------+
```

Keep in mind that only one `Alternative` is listed in the data but in my actual pivot there are a lot more alternatives.

Is there a way to reference the pivot result value cell similar to the above?

Comment: what is your question?

Comment: Added it, basically I don't want to go and select the field first and then set it but rather directly go for it. In large macros this can make a lot of difference.

Comment: `Set rng = pt.PivotFields("Price").PivotItems(1).DataRange` or `Set rng = pt.PivotFields(1).PivotItems(1).DataRange`

Comment: you can get a lot of information by examining `pt.PivotFields("Alternative")` in the _Watch window_.  look for any _range_ objects

Answer (score 0):

here is a bunch of test code that i used to identify ranges in a pivot table

it just does .Select on each range so that the range is visible on the worksheet

some of the ranges are single cells, so .Select can be replaced by .Value

just step code with F8 key and watch the different ranges in the pivot table show up.

```
Sub pivot()

    Dim piv As pivotTable
    Set piv = ActiveSheet.PivotTables("PivotTable3")

    piv.TableRange1.Select
    piv.TableRange2.Select
    piv.DataBodyRange.Select
    piv.RowRange.Select
    piv.ColumnRange.Select
    piv.PageRange.Select
    piv.PageRangeCells.Select


    Dim aaa As Variant
    aaa = piv.DataBodyRange.Value   ' array
    aaa = piv.DataBodyRange.Value2  ' array
    aaa = piv.DataBodyRange.Formula ' array

    piv.DataBodyRange.PivotField.LabelRange.Select
    piv.DataBodyRange.PivotField.DataRange.Select

    piv.DataBodyRange.Next.PivotField.LabelRange.Select
    piv.DataBodyRange.Next.PivotField.DataRange.Select

    piv.DataBodyRange.PivotItem.LabelRange.Select
    piv.DataBodyRange.PivotItem.DataRange.Select

    piv.PivotFields("Price").LabelRange.Select
    piv.PivotFields("Price").DataRange.Select

    piv.PivotFields("ft").LabelRange.Select
    piv.PivotFields("ft").DataRange.Select

    piv.PivotFields("Costs").LabelRange.Select
    piv.PivotFields("Costs").DataRange.Select

End Sub
```

Comment: I will have a look at this but you transformed the `pivot table`. This isn't what I was looking for. I have two column headers and it needs to stay that way.

Comment: this is only an exploration of different ranges available in a pivot table and how rows, columns and cells can be referenced as ranges

Comment: i tried to duplicate your pivot table, but i had no luck. now that you mentioned the two column headers, i see what i missed. not sure what the original data would look like. i think that your diagram needs another horizontal line right above the word "Price"

Comment: i think that i was able to duplicate your pivot table and i replaced the posted code.  data table is 4 columns ... alternative/price/length/cost ... pivot fields are:  _alternative_ - filters .... _length_ and _cost_ - values (named _ft_ and _costs_)   .... _price_ - rows .... Values - columns. i hope it works for you

Comment: Let me check next week, will let you know.